# jQuery trigger event and send backspace key to input, but input text could not be deleted at all

Tags: javascript, jquery, keyevent, eventtrigger, jquery-events

I have below codes to delete input text.

```
$(document).on('click', "button[id='del_btn']", function(event) {
  $("input[id='lvl4_text1']").select()
  $("input[id='lvl4_text1']").focus()
  //trigger backspace keycode 8, keydown and keyup envent to input
  var e = $.Event('keydown', {
    keyCode: 8,
    which: 8
  })
  $("input[id='lvl4_text1']").trigger(e)

  e = $.Event('keyup', {
    keyCode: 8,
    which: 8
  })
  $("input[id='lvl4_text1']").trigger(e)
});

//I can see keyup and keydown event was triggered successfully.
$(document).on('keyup', "input[id='lvl4_text1']", function(event) {
  console.log("level 4 text keyup" + event.which)
});

$(document).on('keydown', "input[id='lvl4_text1']", function(event) {
  console.log("level 4 text down" + event.which)
});
```

it is quite straightforward and simple, but the text in input was not deleted.
I am using chrome55 and jquery1.8.

I do not want a workaround to delete input text, just would like to know why backspace keyboard evnet was triggerd already, but input text was not deleted.
and I tried trigger delete key(keycode 46) event also, nothing changed as same. I also trigger 'a'(keycode 65) to input, but input text can not be replaced.

I am newbie to js/jquery, can any one help?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend splitting the input into an array, removing the last part of the array

```
myarray.pop()
```

Then joining it back into a regular sentence, to then focus on the input.

Also, .trigger() triggers it for jQuery, but does not create the actual event as though the delete button is being pressed on your keyboard.